Is it possible to show a custom woocommerce error page when max_queries in sql is reached?
I have tried to figure this out for a while now. We use a webhost now that is not exactly helpful but for now we have to stay with them.
Our webhost has a max_queries limit in mysql for 360.000. Now and then this limit is reached and the installation page shows.
My question is:
Is there any way to make a custom page like a 404-page when this limit is reached, in stead of showing the installation page?
I have looked around but cant figure this out. All help is really appreciated.
I have tried to disable some of the add-ins without success. I have tried some of the guides found on google that refers to table-prefix and so on.
